# Are repeated sins forgiven or not

Tags: paap, lust

If a person repeats a sin maybe 30 to 75 times.Would he /she be forgiven or not?

[Sin is  one disrespects his teachers, parents,society and even god .Also ,indulging in few wrong acts like abusing,moving towards Lustful actions and also breaking promise to change.]

I have not cause any physical harm to anyone except myself after all this. I know lust and anger are path to self destruction and hell.

My main question is one who has walked on wrong path for so long, how could he be turned to right one and avoid hell? How can one easily leave bad attachment (leaving all attachment isn't possible for me right now) ?
[Please answer from vedas/upnishads etc. ]

Comment: I am admitting my mistake that due to problems and anger I have blamed God for it.

Comment: The problem is that you do not understand the basics about *God*, *Yourself* or even the world, which is why you seem to ask such questions, that treat *god* like a human being (the actual god is far from incarnation or being a human, in all interpretations). Once your basic concepts get strong, such questions might not arise back to you.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, effect of sins can be washed away. You must not, however, commit sins again.

**How to get rid of the effect of sins**

> Yudhisthira says,’…a perpetrated sin is expiated by **auspicious acts**,
> by **publishing it wildly**, by **repentance**, by **alms-giving**, by **penances**,
> by **trips to tirthas after renunciation of everything**, by **constant
> meditation on the scriptures**. Of all these, he that has practiced
> renunciation is believed to be incapable of committing sins anew.

**Mahabharata Santi Parva Section VII**

> ‘Vyasa said, 'By penances, religious rites, and gifts, O Bharata, a
> **man may wash off his sins if he does not commit them again**. By
> **subsisting upon only one meal a day**, that procured by mendicancy, by
> **doing all his acts himself** (without relying on the aid of a
> servant)....by **becoming a brahmacharin** (celibate) and always ready for
> exertion, by **casting off all malice**, by **sleeping on bare ground**, by
> **publishing his offence to the world**, by **doing all this for full 12
> years, a person can cleanse himself from his sin** ......'

**Mahabharata, Santi Parva, Section 36**

Answer (score 0):

When you turn on a light in a room, does the darkness go away slowly or suddenly? Sincere prayer to God washes away everything. Sri Krishna says in *Gita* 18.66 (Swami Nikhilananda translator):

> Abandon all dharmas and come to Me alone for shelter. I will deliver you from all sins; do not grieve.

and in *Gita* 9.29-32:

> I am the same towards all beings; to Me there is none that is hateful or dear. But those who worship Me with unswerving devotion--they are in Me and I too am in them.
>
> Even the most sinful of man, if he worships Me with unswerving devotion, must be regarded as righteous; for he has formed the right resolution.
>
> He soon becomes righteous and attains eternal peace. Proclaim it boldly, O son of Kunti, that My devotee never perishes.
>
> For those who take refuge in Me, O Partha, though they be of sinful birth--women, vaisyas, and sudras--even they attain the Supreme Goal.

If you walk from Mumbai to Delhi, every time you take a step in the direction of Delhi, you get further away from Mumbai.

Answer (score 0):

Hinduism is very clear: It is "no joke" religion as God's GITA says that sinned may attain good path. God did not confirm that sinned will get liberated.
There is no concept of forgiving sins.

Sins in hinduism are in Janma bucket. The sins bucket has to be destroyed by Holy deeds only.
Sins incurred in Janma are not forgiven but can be washed away by tough procedures/ penance.